# angular form stops on first validation error leaving $error in incorrect state

Tags: angularjs

I have an email field in my form that is validated for both being not empty and a valid email. The code is as follows (see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/etQYvORPfUXR059kcbUR?p=preview) - Angular `1.3.0-beta.13`):

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
  <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
  <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Missing Email</span> |
  <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid Email</span>
  <pre>myForm.email.$error: {{  myForm.email.$error | json }}</pre>
</form>
```

When started, only the "Missing Email" message is shown, as expected. When I start typing in the input, both messages `Missing Email` and `Invalid Email` are shown even if the field is **not** empty! This is not expected.

[image]

When typing a valid email, both errors disappear, as expected:

[image]

When getting from the valid email state to invalid email state (by delete characters), only the invalid email message shows, as expected:

[image]

It seems that angular stops on the first validation violation leaving the $error object in a stale state.

Is this a bug in the framework? am I missing something here?

Comment: You might be missing something. This is working as expected in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/I22bq88RvARpfMB2U8LL?p=preview).

Comment: @SunilD. I am using angular 1.3.0

Comment: There won't be a value saved in the model value until there is a "valid" value, so therefore the value of `email` is undefined until you type something.  The reason it works the second time is because there is still a value for the model after putting the space.  Just add a `{{ email}}` to see the output in real time and you will see.

Comment: @JoseM any documentation or rationale on why the model generated by the form for the input fields is not updated? Even if the model is not updated I still expect the validation rules to run to completion and not stop and leave a stale $error object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7849) in angularjs 1.3.0 beta (up to beta.13 at least). A [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/7868) is pending.